# Proftp directory permissions

Tags: centos6, proftpd

I am having an issue getting ProFTP permissions to "work".

I have a series of folders under `/home` and have chrooted all users except for one to their home directory - for example when user 12345 logs in then connect to `/` which is actually `/home/12345`

I would like ftpadm to be able to do anything but all other users only allow users to upload files and deny everything else including listing files so I added this to `/etc/proftpd.conf` and restarted proftpd:

```
<Directory /home>
    <Limit ALL>
      AllowUser ftpadm
      DenyAll
    </Limit>

    <Limit STOR>
      AllowAll
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

However, this allows users to upload and ftpadm can browse any directory but 12345 can create directories, create files, edit files, list and more - how can I lock all users except for one down only being able to upload files?

Answer (score 0):

You might try using something like this:

```
<Directory />
  <Limit STOR STOU>
    AllowUser ftpadm
    DenyAll
  </Limit>
</Directory>
```

The ProFTPD [Limits](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Limit.html) howto has more examples which also be of interest.

Hope this helps!